# Simple way to analysis log file and display the result

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, log-analysis

I have a log file. I want to upload the log file and I want to do some query on the log file then I want to display the result. What is the simplest way to do this work? Is it possible to do with only Elastic search and Kibana without using logstash?

Answer (score 0):

You need something to send the log file to elasticsearch, it could be a Logstash instance, Filebeat or a custom application/script.

With Logstash you will have more freedom if you want to parse the message or enrich the data, Filebeat is more limited on these aspects.

On my case I use both Logstash and Filebeat, I have a Logstash machine that receives the data sent by Filebeat agents installed on remote machines.

Answer (score 0):

You need a log forwarder to read your log file and push them into elasticsearch cluster.
Famous log forwarders are,

1. `logstash` (which not only read log file and push log lines into elasticseach, but also you can perform intermediate filtering and formatting before you send each log line)
2. `file-beat` (a very light weight agent which read log lines from file and push into elasticsearch cannot perform intermediate filtering or formatting)